# what is the proper terminal syntax of this python image conversion tool

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to use this image conversion tool, but the example is too vague for me.  The utility is here: [Image convertor](http://www.byvac.com/downloads/BV4612/bv4612_image_convert.zip)

In this zip folder is the python file bmpcf.py   When I open this file I get the following message below. I assume I am to type like the example into the terminal window, but I can get the figure out the syntax. (the example given doesn't seem to have any reference to a bmp file???)  My test bmp file to convert is called 35x35.bmp  Do I need to put it or this python script in a particular place?  I've tried several different places, and tried using the full path, but can't figure it out.  Thanks so much.

This is the 'Help Message' that comes up when clicking on the bmpcf.py file:

```
Last login: Mon Nov 16 08:13:56 on ttys001
cd '/Users/myname/Downloads/bv4612_image_convert/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/myname/Downloads/bv4612_image_convert/bmpcf.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
myname-MacBook-Air:~ myname$ cd '/Users/myname/Downloads/bv4612_image_convert/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/myname/Downloads/bv4612_image_convert/bmpcf.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1

Conversion utility for 128x64 type graphic display
Converts a bmp file into verical 8 bit lines for 
applying to the display pages

Use <filename> <hex/bin> <format>
filename   is the full file name including bmp
hex        is 1 for hex or 0 for decimal
format     b for use with ByPic (.bas)
           c for use with C/C++ (.h)
           t text fomat (.txt)
           i binary format (.bin)
output will be a text file

Example python.py bmpcf.py 1 b

Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```